# MySQL master slave replication issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have enabled filtered replication in MySQL. Only one table is being replicated from master to slave using replicate-do-table option and the replication is going smooth. Today morning I have noticed that a newly created procedure in master got replicated to the slave. Any ideas?

Comment: What `USE` did you execute before the `CREATE PROCEDURE`?  Was the table in question in the proc?  Do you have only one `replicate_...` statement?

Comment: The procedure is created in the SAME DB where the replicated table is. But the table is not used anywhere in the procedure. I have only one table replicated using replicate-do-table